# Java priority queue implementation - memory locality

Tags: java, heap, memory-management, priority-queue

I am trying to implement an efficient priority queue in Java. I got to a good implementation of a binary heap but it doesn't have the ideal cache performance. For this I started studying the Van Emde Boas layout in a binary heap which led me to a "blocked" version of a binary heap, where the trick is to calculate the children and parent indices.

Although I was able to do this, the cache behavior (and running time) got worse. I think that the problem is: **locality of reference** is probably not being achieved, since it is Java - **I'm not so sure if using an array of objects actually makes objects to be contiguous in memory in Java**, can anyone confirm this please?

Also I would like very much to know what kind of data-structures Java's native PriorityQueue uses, if any would know.

Comment: Array of objects is an array of *references* to objects. Objects are in heap. No locality whatsoever, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there is no good way to force your objects in the queue to occupy a contiguous chunk of memory. There are, however, some techniques that are suitable for special cases.

At a high level, the techniques involve using byte arrays and 'serializing' data to and from the array. This is actually quite effective if you are storing very simple objects. For example, if you are storing a bunch of 2D points + weights, you can simply write byte equivalent of the weight, x-coordinate, y-coordinate.

The problem at this point, of course, is in allocating instances while peeking/popping. You can avoid this by using a callback.

Note that even in cases where the object being stored itself is complex, using a technique similar to this where you keep one array for the weights and a separate array of references for the actual objects allows you to avoid following the object reference until absolutely necessary.

Going back to the approach for storing simple immutable value-type, here's an incomplete sketch of what you could do:

```
abstract class LowLevelPQ<T> {

  interface DataHandler<R, T> {
    R handle(byte[] source, int startLoc);
  }

  LowLevelPQ(int entryByteSize) { ... }
  abstract encode(T element, byte[] target, int startLoc);
  abstract T decode(byte[] source, int startLoc);
  abstract int compare(byte[] data, int startLoc1, int startLoc2);

  abstract <R> R peek(DataHandler<R, T> handler) { ... }
  abstract <R> R pop(DataHandler<R, T> handler) { ... }
}

class WeightedPoint {
  WeightedPoint(int weight, double x, double y) { ... }
  double weight() { ... }
  double x() { ... }
  ...
}

class WeightedPointPQ extends LowLevelPQ<WeightedPoint> {
  WeightedPointPQ() {
    super(4 + 8 + 8); // int,double,double
  }

  int compare(byte[] data, int startLoc1, int startLoc2) {
    // relies on Java's big endian-ness
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      int v1 = 0xFF & (int) data[startLoc1];
      int v2 = 0xFF & (int) data[startLoc2];
      if (v1 < v2) { return -1; }
      if (v1 > v2) { return  1; }
    }
    return 0;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Although I trust a version like that would behave good in terms of cache memory, it will certainly generate a lot of overhead when I'm looking for something as simple as contiguous elements in memory. Anyways, thank you for your concern =)

Comment: Yes, this approach works when you store a very large number of elements, but access few of them at any time.

Comment: By the way, in this implementation, what kind of data-structure are you storing the elements in? Byte array, ByteBuffer or something like that?

Comment: Yes, a byte array. This is the classic array for PQ algorithm, where element[0] is at the top, and element[2i], element[2i + 1] are lower priority that element[i]. The only detail is that all indexing needs to be multiplied by entryByteSize.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would.  Remember, "arrays of objects" aren't arrays of objects, they are arrays of object references (unlike arrays of primitives which really are arrays of the primitives).  I'd expect the object references are contiguous in memory, but since you can make those references refer to any objects you want whenever you want, I doubt there's any guarantee that the objects referred to by the array of references will be contiguous in memory.

For what it's worth, the [JLS section on arrays](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html) says nothing about any guarantees of contiguousness.

Comment: Isn't there a way to force objects to be contiguous in java data-structures? I've been browsing around and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106978/can-array-access-be-optimized/4107431#4107431. I think I'm gonna try this, although I'm not too confident it will behave good in a heap context. Thanks

Comment: Only an array of primitives stores them within the same heap block. No way to force childs of Object to be placed into adjacent addresses.

Comment: Just to clarify this topic, now that my research as gone clearer. Java does not allow array-element contiguity, however there are a number of considerations to take such as allocation time (it is very likely the JVM/GC will allocate contiguously if elements are closely instantiated), also if we need to go deeper there are some  optimization spots to consider in JVM level and Garbage Collecting implementations ([Jikes](http://jikesrvm.org/) implements a locality optimizing GC by identifying _hot_ fields).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some FUD going on here. It is basically inconceivable that any implementation of arrays would not use contiguous memory. And the way the term is used in the JVM specification when describing the .class file format makes it pretty clear that no other implementation is contemplated.

java.util.PriorityQueue uses a binary heap, as it says in the Javadoc, implemented via an array.

Comment: So, is it worth to try to implement a cache-aware/oblivious version of a PriorityQueue (or any data-structure for that matter)? I read that native java PQ uses a binary heap, but I didn't know it was array based. However, when I profile me versions java's PQ, Java's has a much better cache behavior - I would like to know what kind of methodologies they are using for this. I've searched around but didn't find anything.

Comment: They aren't using any methodology for this that I can see. They are just using a pretty vanilla implementation of a binary heap. If you want comments on your own code, post it.